# Error con cuenta regresiva

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando el siguiente código para hacer cuenta regresiva. 
¿Por qué me toma erróneo el horario actual?
Entiendo que `new Date()` es la hora actual.

Por ejemplo aparece -1 dia -5horas.

```
  //$endtime= 2020-02-25 23:57:31

    var countDownDate = new Date("'. date('d M Y H',strtotime($end_date)) .'").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();


  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  document.getElementById("demodia").innerHTML =  days ;
    document.getElementById("demohora").innerHTML = hours ;
    document.getElementById("demomin").innerHTML =  minutes ;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "FINALIZADA";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: hola, deberias poner todas las variables que usas en el codigo que muestras, //$endtime= 2020-02-25 23:57:31 --> y usas $end_date
    var countDownDate = new Date("'. date('d M Y H',strtotime($end_date)) .'").getTime();
Si la variable countDownDate es menor a now, siempre sera negativa, deberias reformular tu pregunta.

Comment: El órden de la resta debería ser la fecha actual primero: now - countDownDate